# Better way to insert values in xml python 2.7

Tags: python, xml, soap

I've been looking around for a better solution that what I'm already doing. I need to construct an xml to send to a SOAP service but I need to generate the XML dinamically. The problem or may not be a problem, is that I find this really long and I think there must be a better way of achiving this. I'm using python 2.7.5, this is my XML (kind of, it's actually larger):

```
SINGLE_PAYMENT = '''...
<v1:Shipping>
            <v1:Type>%s</v1:Type>
            <v1:Address1>%s</v1:Address1>
            <v1:Address2>%s</v1:Address2>
            <v1:City>%s</v1:City> 
            <v1:Country>%s</v1:Country>
            <v1:Items>%s</v1:Items>
            <v1:State>%s</v1:State>
            <v1:Carrier>%s</v1:Carrier>
            <v1:Weight>%s</v1:Weight>
            <v1:Total>%s</v1:Total>
 </v1:Shipping>
 ....'''
```

Then I do

```
SoapMessage = SINGLE_PAYMENT%...and replace here with variables passed to this function
```

Is there any better way of doing this?.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a proper [XML library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml), or you could just write a method that generates a single "shipping" element using templates, for example:

```
def generate_tag(name, values, version='1'):
    return '\n'.join([
        '<v{0}:{1}>'.format(version, name),
        '\n'.join(
            '\t<v{2}:{0}>{1}</v{2}:{0}>'.format(k, v, version) for k, v in values.iteritems()
        ),
        '</v{0}:{1}>'.format(version, name)
    ])

# Output:
>>> print generate_tag('Shipping', {"Total": "100", "Type": "A"})
<v1:Shipping>
    <v1:Total>100</v1:Total>
    <v1:Type>A</v1:Type>
</v1:Shipping>
```

But, as you can see, that gets messy quickly.

Using the libraries (such as [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) or [MiniDom](https://wiki.python.org/moin/MiniDom)) would be more to your benefit, though, as they will take care of any needed escaping and provide a better interface should you need to make changes later.